# Scheme Maintaining Value throughout program

Tags: function, scheme, constants

In the following code the values for avg and avg2 change as the code progresses. How can I make it so that the values are constant throughout the function without defining them outside the function? Should I use a helper function?

```
(define (covariance-list x y)
  (let ((avg (average x)))
  (let ((avg2 (average y)))
  (if (null? x) 
      '()
      (cons (* (- (car x) avg)(- (car y) avg2)) 
            (covariance-list (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be with an auxiliary function:

```
(define (covariance-list x y)
  (define (covariance-list-aux x y avg-x avg-y)
    (if (null? x)
      '()
      (cons (* (- (car x) avg-x) (- (car y) avg-y))
            (covariance-list-aux (cdr x) (cdr y) avg-x avg-y))))
  (covariance-list-aux x y (average x) (average y)))
```

Comment: You should try to avoid passing avg-x and avg-y recursively all the time.

Comment: @uselpa, because they are consuming stack, you mean?

Comment: Because you get the impression that they may change (why else would you want to pass them over and over again?), but they don't.

Comment: @uselpa, that is an interesting design constraint / coding standard. I can see the logic of it. However, I pass constants to procedures all the time. Is there a coding standard you can refer me to (perhaps scheme specific) that elaborates on that idea?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want them constant, since they depend on the parameters of the function.  You probably just want them to not be recomputed during each recursive call.

```
(define (covariance-list x y)
 (let ((avg (average x))
       (avg2 (average y)))
     (let loop ((x x)
                (y y))
       (if (null? x)
         '()
          (cons (* (- (car x) avg)
                   (- (car y) avg2))
                (loop (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
```